# Como enviar contenido de un listbox por email en c#

Tags: c#

intento enviar por correo todos los items que tiene mi listbox 
      Actualmente intento asignar los valores a una variable string para llamar con msg.Body = resultado pero me envia un mensaje en balnco

```
 private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
  CNSueldo objn = new CNSueldo();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
   foreach (object item in listBox1.SelectedItems)
  {
   sb.Append(item.ToString() + ", ");
  }
  string resultado = sb.ToString();
```

Comment: Saludos Gian, lectura obligatoria: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 además de visitar https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Bienvenido, Por favor edita tu pregunta revisa [ask], añade detalles, lo que has investigado, saludos.

Comment: Que hay dentro de sb cuando le haces toString()?

Comment: lo que quise guardar en sb fue el contenido de un listbox

Answer (score 0):

Solo remplaza

```
foreach (object item in listBox1.SelectedItems)
```

por

```
foreach (object item in listBox1.Items)
```

SelectedItems (elemento seleccionado) busca al elemento que se ha seleccionado (si te aparece en blanco es por que no se ha seleccionado ninguno, y si seleccionas uno, con tu codigo actual solo mostrará el que hayas seleccionado), si quieres que tome en cuenta todos, solo indica Items (elementos).